# I want to split an array into multiple arrays

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have an array like so:

```
mainarray=[[a,b,c],[1,2,3]]
```

Now I want the above array to be split into two individual arrays.
Like:

```
array1=[a,b,c]
```

and

```
array2=[1,2,3].
```

So I tried by using objectatindex method:

```
NSString *string1=[mainarray objectatindex:0];
[array1 addobject:string1];
```

But I got the array as:

```
array1=[[a,b,c],];
```

and

```
array2=[[1,2,3],];
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two arrays that you want are already arrays that are elements of `mainArray`, so just access them:

```
NSArray *array1 = mainarray[0];
NSArray *array2 = mainarray[1];
```

That is all.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm trying objective-c, I think I should use-

```
NSArray *array1=[mainarray objectatindex:0];
NSArray *array2=[mainarray objectatindex:1];
```